# How to handle OS signal in a python program?

Tags: python, signals

I am writing a python program which reads from a queue through a infinite while loop. How can I handle signal sent by OS / Keyboard interrupt(CTRL+C) to break from the while loop and close active connections and files and exit the program gracefully instead of killing the process.

```
while True:
    read_from_file_and_do_something()
    ## Handle a signal of shutdown here.
    ## Send email before exiting.
```

This program will run as a daemon. Thus would require a signal to be sent.

Answer (score 3):

I think [signal](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/signal.html#signal.signal) module is what you are looking for,

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum

signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, handler)
```

Comment: Where exactly should I use this? Inside the loop?

Comment: at ##handle signal  `signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, handler)` and  perform aftertask in handler function with exit code

Comment: @nagato is there a way to handle multiple signal types with the same handler nicely? (e.g. INT, ABRT, HUP together for example)