# handling unexpected shutdown python

Tags: python

is there any way to catch an exception for an unexpected shutdown of program in python ?

let say I am running a python script in a console then I don't press **control+c** to stop the program but rather just click the close button of the console is there any way to catch the error before the console close?

like this:

```
try:
    print("hello")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
except UnexpectedClose:
    print("unexpected shutoff")
    exit()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Youll probably need to catch a `signal` event

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5180440/2308683

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33234055/2308683

Comment: I'm not sure if a SIGKILL event can be caught.

Comment: don't work @cricket_007

Comment: ...and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully)...SIGKILL?

Comment: "don't work" is not very descriptive. Show the code you tried

Comment: i use the code from the first solution but seems that when I press the close button of the terminal there are no print before the close of terminal

Answer (score 0):

Following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464349/803359) I put in the comment above already and reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5547386/803359) that forced closing is sending a `SIGHUP` this modified version writes an output file when the terminal window is closed and the python process is "killed".

Note, I just combined information (as cited) available on SE.

```
import signal
import time

class GracefulKiller:
    kill_now = False
    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self,signum, frame):
        with open('kill.txt', 'w') as fpntr:
            fpntr.write('killed')
        self.kill_now = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    killer = GracefulKiller()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("doing something in a loop ...")
        if killer.kill_now:
            break
    print "End of the program. I was killed gracefully :)"
```